# Create a Swarm in multiple docker-compose with multi-host with dedicated servers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have three servers each having defined docker containers by compose. I need to encrypt the communication between two of them and in the future I'll need replicas in at least one.

So I thought to create a swarm with overlay network, but I need each container to continue running in their currently dedicated server, so I cannot create a swarm with three nodes (one per server) and let the manager schedule the services replication.

So I've though about creating a swarm per each compose, so that when I need more nodes for some compose, I'll add a new dedicated server for this compose and it'll be added to the swarm of this compose as a node.

What I don't really know is if this is the best way to solve this architecture also how can be established the encrypted communication between the swarms directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you need multiple swarm clusters, since docker swarm supports ability scheduling service on specific node(s) by one flag.

Add `--constraint` flag when executing `docker service create`.

If you are deploying applications with docker compose, then add `constraints` keyword in compose file.

```
constraints: [node.hostname == node_server]
```

Some [introduction about constraint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints---constraint).

Comment: This works for me, but I'm using docker-compose version 3.3 so I have added the flags to the compose file used to launch it:

 placement:
              constraints: [node.hostname == node_server]